# Generating Java classes from XML file

Tags: java, xml, class

How can I get java classes from an xml file?

In this situation, I don't have an **XML schema** and this way I can't use JAXB, Castor or other xml binding API as far as I know.

Comment: Can you describe what you want this xml file to describe? You say you don't have a schema, but are you interested in generating classes from something approximating a schema?

Comment: If you "can't use" any of the binding APIs i don't see any other way than to parse the DOM tree and create objects yourself. But why can't you use JAXB which is included in the more recent JDKs?

Comment: jaxb requires a schema, which he doesn't have. There's plenty of tools that tries to generate a schema out of example xml files though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate schema from XML file using [certain tools](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2106). Then, use [Apache XMLBEANS](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to create your classes.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo. I could use a program from the "certain tools" list to get the schema from the xml file. Now is easy to convert it to java classes using JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

[XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) is great for XML -> objects and vice versa. Fast, lightweight, and works well without any schema.

Comment: The problem is generating the java class from an example xml file.  XStream is great at taking existing classes and converting to/from XML, not so good when you only have the xml.

Comment: This link to XStream no longer works - it goes to a server which requires authentication.  Is part of the path missing?

Answer (score -1):

[Altova](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is also the best to generate java Classes from XML/XSD