# XML to POJO in Java

Tags: java

I am looking out for XML to POJO creation framework i.e. I have a XML file and from that I wants to create / generates POJO class.

I am not going to create this POJO class in my app,actuall i am  looking out for plugin/framework that reads XML and gives me POJO class accordingly!

Please suggest!

Comment: Google JAXB Unmarhsalling: Converting XML to Java Object. Ex http://www.journaldev.com/1234/jaxb-tutorial-example-to-convert-object-to-xml-and-xml-to-object

Comment: I saw this ..but given code just give you java obj and not create actual POJO class!

Comment: You can use JAXB. Also, [check this site](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/jaxb-sax-dom-performance.html) for the performance

Comment: @prady Where does the xml come from? Is it auto-generated? How does it look? Is it a WSDL?

Comment: Hi, It is not WSDL..but similar to SOAP message....it is stored in local drive (C:\ drive)

Comment: I tried JAXB..XSTREAM, POJOXML API's ...but all thease are giving me java obj of XML and not creating POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Generating Java classes from XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447213/generating-java-classes-from-xml-file)

Generate a schema from the XML and then use [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)